# What does this php code mean? And how can i use it to access a web server through a login page?

Tags: php, cookies, web, server-side

What does this PHP code mean?

```
< ?php
$userAccess = isset($_COOKIE['userLoggedIn'])
  ? true
  : false;
?>
```

And how can I use it to access a web server through a login page?

Answer (score 0):

```
$userAccess = isset($_COOKIE['userLoggedIn']) ? true : false;
```

Your given line is called [ternary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). It means if `$_COOKIE['userLoggedIn']` variable is set/ defined in the current page then `$userAccess` variable will set true otherwise it will set false as boolean.

you can use the below code to check user login in your web page.

```
if($userAccess){
echo "Successfully Logged In.";
} else {
echo "Login Failed!";
}
```

Hope it helps you.